# Synchronize Two Media Elements in Two Forms in WPF?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I'm doing a music project.  I want it to have two forms: one is playback, another is manager.  When a media element in the first form is playing and I switch to another form, I want the media element in that form to be playing the same as the media element in the first form.  I tried to do that, but when I switch forms (when I close the first form) the song pauses a bit. I want the sound to be playing without pause like Media Windows Player.

Comment: Can you provide some examples of the code you are working on?

Comment: Andrew, Can you suggest any solution to me? My code is simple, assign source of 2 mediaElement and switch to play.

Comment: Sorry Ly Hung, I am not a WPF expert; I was hoping to help you improve your question.  Cheers~

Comment: Some things that may help are using multiple threads for parts of the application. But without a code sample in your question it's hard to offer suggestions.